# Tab issue in android with back button

Tags: android

I am using tab host(tabs) in application, it have four tabs on home screen, I have set new layouts on every tabs, I want to that once user clicking tabs like: tab1>tab2>tab3>tab4 and press back on tab4 he/she should go back to tab3 and on tab3 pressing back go to tab2 and so on. I didn't get any idea, how to implement? Could any one help me on this, any help will be appreciated. Thanking you all..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the below method in your class which extends TabActivity,

```
public void switchTabBar(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab); 
    }
```

And now in your activity's back press method, do  this,

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    TabBar parentTab = (TabBar) this.getParent();
        parentTab.switchTabBar(1);//Instead of 1 provide the tab position which you want to navigate to. 

}
```

Comment: Hi Selva, I got the Idea, but don't knw how the TabBar is showing error in my activity, Is I need to extends any class or somthing else in Acitity (in which I overriding onBackPressed()). Thanking you for your help.

Comment: You have to extend Activity only. Can I just know what kind of error u r running into. Bcoz I am not sure abt it

Comment: I am using api level 7.
The error message is as "TabBar cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: My Friend TabBar is not a inbuilt class. I am sorry. Please provide the name of the class which extends your Tab Activity. did u get what I am trying to say?

Comment: You are great, it worked. Thanks dost...!! 
It will much help if you can advise that from which tab I had come so I will be track and redirect to user from where he/she come. Actualy tabhost (tabs widget) is new for me. Hope you understand..!!

Comment: but how r u planning on doing that. Already with this piece of code you are overriding the back press event, so my question is there wont be any other way for you to redirect the user to where he came from. It is not possible. But still if you can find out any nice and easier way to do this it is better. Sorry I couldn't help you on this.

Comment: Actualy, now I am able to switch tabs by overridding back button, but now I have to track that from which tab he came from (I think you understand) and I have to switch on that tab, so application behave like he is going back by pressing back. I know it's not good Idea to do but I have to do as per the requirement.

Comment: I am sorry my friend. I have no ide on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can override `onBackPressed()` and inside it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some sort of a activities-backstack (if you use nested ActivityGroup), override `onBackPressed()` method in your TabActivity and manage this backstack in `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:- with Tab or without Tab.

If it is not necessary that you have to use tab in your code then instead of tab you can use buttons and you can easily get your goal. But if you want to use tab then you have to Override `onBackPressed()` in every 4 `Activity`.

I hope you got any idea according to my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to add back button.In tabs there's no need to add back button.See the below link

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html